# npm related tasks are throwing errors during installations

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webdev.webserver

I've been having this problem recently that nothing related to npm is working for me except `npm start`.

`npm install` is giving this error:

> ```
> $ npm install @material-ui/core
> npm ERR! Object for dependency "@babel/generator" is empty.
> npm ERR! Something went wrong. Regenerate the package-lock.json with "npm install".
> npm ERR! If using a shrinkwrap, regenerate with "npm shrinkwrap".
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!   C:\Users\Parth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-20T13_52_13_701Z-debug.log
> ```

`npx create-react-app ./` is giving this error:

> ```
> npx create-react-app ./
> npx: installed 98 in 10.023s
>
> Creating a new React app in G:\hel.
>
> Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes. Installing
> react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
>
> yarn add v1.22.4 [1/4] Resolving packages... [2/4] Fetching
> packages... error An unexpected error occurred: "UNKNOWN: unknown
> error, unlink
> 'C:\\Users\\Parth\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v6\\npm-core-js-pure-3.6.4-4bf1ba866e25814f149d4e9aaa08c36173506e3a-integrity\\node_modules\\core-js-pure\\features\\object\\is-frozen.js'".
> info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the
> information provided in "G:\\hel\\yarn-error.log". info Visit
> https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
>
> Aborting installation.   yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom
> react-scripts cra-template --cwd G:\hel has failed.
>
> Deleting generated file... package.json Deleting generated file...
> yarn.lock Done.
> ```

**EDIT:** So I tried using Yarn for my installs but got this error:

> ```
> $ yarn add @material-ui/core
> yarn add v1.22.4
> warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by
> tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to
> avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear
> this warning, remove package-lock.json.
>    [1/4] Resolving packages...
>    [2/4] Fetching packages...
>    error An unexpected error occurred: "UNKNOWN: unknown error, unlink 
> 'C:\\Users\\Parth\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v6\\npm-core-js-pure-3.6.4-4bf1ba866e25814f149d4e9aaa08c36173506e3a-integrity\\node_modules\\core-js-pure\\features\\object\\is-frozen.js'".
> info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information
> provided in "F:\\Parth\\covid-19-tracker\\yarn-error.log".
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
> ```

How do I fix this?

**Edit:** My version of `npm` is `6.14.8`

Comment: You use yarn or npm??

Comment: I always use npm but after getting this error multiple times i tried yarn and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you need to make sure that your node and npm versions are up to date. if not please upgrade your node and npm packages to latest versions.

```
nvm install 12.18.3 // update node version through node version manager

npm install npm // update your npm version to latest
```

Delete your `node_modules` folder, `package-lock.json` and `yarn` file (if you have).

Force clean the entire NPM cache by using following comand.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Re-Install all the dependencies.

```
npm install
```

If above step didn't resolve your problem, try to uninstall `yarn` globally by delete the `Yarn` folder from global folder and then run.

```
npm uninstall -g yarn
```

Comment: Okay so npm installs didn't work so i had couldn't even launch the updates BUT deleting those files fixed it all instantly. Mainly felt like the yarn files were causing the issues. npx create-react-app still didn't work so i just uninstalled yarn globally and now everything is working just fine. Thanks. Any idea why it all happened in the first place?

Comment: `yarn` is equivalent of `npx`. The error might be a result of a conflict while integrating each other. not sure..

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem after I tried to delete `node_module` unseccessfully.
It didn't let me delete the rest of that directory, even part of it.
from the file explirer I tried to delete, to remove - with no help
So I **renamed the directory** (this is the only action left to do..) and then ran `npm install`
that fixed the problem

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34345875)

Comment: But this answer is helpful.